# While loop in bash + postgresql date | operator does not exist: date = integer

Tags: postgresql, bash

I'm quite newbie and although I've spent some hours already to google up a solution I still failing to resolve this issue - hope someone can help me out, please!

I'm trying to use while loop in bash with a postgresql query which would return me an integer for each date between 2018-01-01 and 2018-03-31.
With my current query I'm getting the following error in bash:

---

```
"HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
ERROR:  operator does not exist: date = integer
LINE 8:     WHERE event_date=2018-01-02"
```

---

And the way I've tried to run the loop (scrip via mcedit) is:

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

d=2018-01-01
while [ "$d" != 2018-04-01 ]; do.
psql -U dataguy -d postgres -c"
    SELECT event_date, COUNT(DISTINCT(id)) as daily_active_users FROM
    (SELECT event_type, country, id, CAST(NULL as INT) AS price, event_date FROM returners
    UNION ALL
    SELECT event_type, NULL AS country, id, CAST(NULL as INT) AS price, event_date FROM sub
    UNION ALL
    SELECT event_type, NULL AS country, id, price, event_date FROM buy) AS returners_sub_buy
    WHERE event_date=$d
    GROUP BY event_date;"
d=$(date -I -d "$d + 1 day")
done
```

---

Any recommendation, advice or hint is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguments usually need to be quoted, like

```
WHERE event_date='2018-01-02'
```

Comment: Thank you - indeed it needs to be quoted and this alone resolved the issue! Shame on me...